# How to specify different palettes and line size within a single ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm displaying four distributions within the same `ggplot2` graph with the following code (data downloadable there: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5j7ckmm5s9lo8j/1.csv?dl=0):

```
require(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

fileName = "./1.csv" # downloadable there: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5j7ckmm5s9lo8j/1.csv?dl=0

mydata = read.csv(fileName,sep=",", header=TRUE)

dataM = melt(mydata,c("bins"))

ggplot(data=dataM, aes(x=bins, y=value, colour=variable)) +
xlab("bins") + ylab("freq") + geom_line(size = .5, alpha = .9) +
scale_colour_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 7) +
geom_line(size = .5, alpha = .9) +
theme_bw() +
theme(plot.background = element_blank()
,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
,axis.line = element_blank()
,legend.key = element_blank()
,legend.title = element_blank()) +
scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

How to change this graph so that B, E and W appear according to a specific palette (say: `scale_colour_brewer`) with a width of .5, while R appears in `scale_colour_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 7)` with a width of 1?

Comment: Subset your data by variable such that R is in a group by itself then you should be able call geom_line twice on each subset.

Comment: Upvote for reproducible example.

Comment: you could probably use a manual colour scale, and a manual size scale

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call subsets of your data in seperate `geom_line`'s:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=dataM[dataM$variable!="R",], aes(x=bins, y=value, colour=variable), size = .5, alpha = .9) +
  geom_line(data=dataM[dataM$variable=="R",], aes(x=bins, y=value, colour=variable), size = 1.5, alpha = .9) +
  scale_colour_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 7) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous("freq", expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_x_continuous("bins", expand=c(0,0))
```

this gives:
[image]

---

Another solution (as suggested by @baptiste) is setting the `size` and `colour` scales manually:

```
ggplot(data=dataM, aes(x=bins, y=value, colour=variable, size = variable)) +
  geom_line(alpha = .9) +
  scale_colour_manual(breaks=c("B","E","W","R"), values=c("green","orange","blue","pink")) +
  scale_size_manual(breaks=c("B","E","W","R"), values=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous("freq", expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_x_continuous("bins", expand=c(0,0))
```

this gives more or less the same result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jaap! It works great except for the palette (all lines use the same "scale_colour_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 7)" palette)

Comment: @Rodolphe Its probably better to use `scale_colour_manual` then. I've also added a second example in which this is illustrated.

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(aes(x=bins, y=value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line(data=dataM[dataM$variable!="R",]) +
  geom_line(data=dataM[dataM$variable=="R",])
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work this way. When you call your data in the geom, you also have to specify the mapping (the `aes()`) in the geom.